# App not Responding While Playing media from url

Tags: android, onclick, android-mediaplayer

I have songs from json in list view, and a play button in each row , after clicking on play Button my app freezes and App not responding dialog box comes, Sometime media player started after freezing sometimes its crashes. Because of App not responsive. This is my Code :

```
  viewHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    selectedPosition = position;

                    if (selectedPosition != mPlayingPosition) {

                        try {
                            mPlayerforplanet.reset();
                            mPlayerforplanet.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            mPlayerforplanet.setDataSource(song_urls);

                            logger.addRecordToLog("MediaPlayer audio session ID: " + mPlayerforplanet.getAudioSessionId());
                            logger.addRecordToLog("Media Player started " + "Started !");
                            mPlayerforplanet.prepare();
                            mPlayerforplanet.start();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        //  playSongs(position);(i also try with method of playsong but no luck)

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "play song" + mPlayingPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }}});
```

Log cat after click on play button

```
01-10 07:13:33.501 17284-17293/luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator I/art: Thread[5,tid=17293,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xab8d8600,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
01-10 07:13:34.273 17284-17293/luck.materialdesign.tabsnavigator I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: I am not sure but once try to create thread for playing music and see your problem solved.

Comment: OK . i will try sir. Is there any tutorial regarding Music player in thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use prepareAsync instead of prepare and handle onPrepared and trigger start from there .

```
 mPlayerforplanet.prepareAsync();
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
  mPlayerforplanet.start;
}
```

sample code :

```
package com.example.simplemediaplayer.app;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MediaPlayerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);

        String url = "http://www.brothershouse.narod.ru/music/pepe_link_-_guitar_vibe_113_club_mix.mp3"; // your URL here
        MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //mp3 will be started after completion of preparing...
        myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                player.start();
            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.media_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

For seek-bar use a anew runnable :

Starting runnable ,

```
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            mPlayerforplanet.start();
            mUpdateSeekBar.run();
        }
```

Code in runnable

```
private final Runnable mUpdateSeekBar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                   int elapsedtime = mPlayerforplanet.getCurrentPosition();
                  /* update UI with getCurrentPosition*/
                mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateSeekBar, 1000);
        }
    };
```

Comment: i also using seekbar and its timings, so after playing from prepared listener "player.start()" not from myMediaPlayer, so how to get timings from media player ?

Comment: bro my timings i get !! media player but seekbar is not running with song .. can you please tell me where to i use seek bar.on-change listener ? in prepared? or in Thread?

Comment: Update seekbar from thread,In every second this thread will execute and take the elapsed time and update the seekbar from there. Don't forget to vote my answer if it's helpful for you. :)

Comment: bro i want reset of media player too.. because i am playing songs in list . can you please tell me where to apply reset? if i put above set data source then it crashes, (-38,0) or you are using get duration of song before start. this error comes...

Comment: You should reset the player before setdatasource.Also you can't get the current duration without starting player. Please see the state diagram of media player in this link <https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html >?

Comment: yeaahh !! thnku bro its works.. my on complete not working bro !! please tell me how to resolve it? thnx bro :)

Comment: Implement MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,Then use the below code    @Override
    `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         playNextSong();
    }`

Comment: bro in playNextSong(); i use above code of yours ? !!

Comment: PlayNextsong function will contains mediaplayer play activities(reset,setdatasource,prapareasync).

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank You :)